# How to do a counter SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been doing this

```
SELECT 
     movi.Usuario AS RowUsuario, movi.MovID, MIN(Art.Descripcion1),
     MIN(com.ReferenciaExtra), MIN(com.Unidad), MIN(Art.UnidadCompra),
     MIN(movi.FechaEmision),
     error = CASE 
        WHEN MIN (com.Unidad) NOT LIKE 
            CASE
               WHEN MIN (ar.Unidad) LIKE com.Unidad THEN art.Unidad
            END 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END
FROM 
    CompraD com
INNER JOIN 
    Mov movi ON com.ID = movi.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Art ON com.Articulo = Art.Articulo
WHERE 
    movi.Mov = 'Requisicion
ORDER BY 
    movi.FechaEmision ASC
```

`when 'com.unidad' dont match with art.Unidad, add 1 or 0 if they match

SQL Server says:

> incorrect syntax CASE

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect syntax error is referring to the

```
error = CASE part.
```

It should be

```
CASE statement END AS error
```

However I'm not sure if that will solve your problem as the case statements looks a little odd to me but get that bit the right way around and then let us know of any further error messages.

Possibly...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN com.Unidad <> ar.Unidad THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS error)
```

Also, you are missing a GROUP BY clause, if you want to use aggregate functions (MIN for example) you need to GROUP BY the non aggregate fields.

Comment: SELECT movi.Usuario AS RowUsuario, movi.MovID, Art.Descripcion1, com.ReferenciaExtra, com.Unidad, Art.UnidadCompra, movi.FechaEmision,
CASE WHEN com.Unidad != Art.Unidad THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
FROM CompraD com
INNER JOIN Mov movi
ON com.ID = movi.ID
INNER JOIN Art
ON com.Articulo = Art.Articulo
WHERE movi.Mov = 'Requisicion' this code works!

Comment: `alias = expression` is a valid syntax in Transact-SQL. It is equivalent to the standard SQL `expression AS alias`, which works in T-SQL too.

Answer (score 0):

You have `WHEN MIN (ar.Unidad) LIKE com.Unidad THEN art.Unidad` but I do not see **ar** aliased anywhere.

Also you need to either have GROUP BY or OVER clause with your MINs.

If you want more details you'll have to give more details and context.